# Сложение времени в php

Tags: php, дата, время, datetime

У меня есть переменная которая генерит время

```
$start_time_with_day = mktime($start_time_arr[0], $start_time_arr[1], 0, $start_day_arr[1], $start_day_arr[2], $start_day_arr[0]);

echo date('H:i d/m/Y ', $start_time_with_day); // выводит 02:55 23/11/2019
```

И у меня есть время, в формате 
22:05, которое нужно добавить к текущей дате. Как мне сложить время, чтобы получить
01:00 24/11/2019 ?

Comment: Сколько часов добовлять? непонятно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Прибавьте время и вычтите полночь

echo date('H:i d/m/Y ', $start_time_with_day) ."\n"; 
// выводит 02:55 23/11/2019

$time = "22:05"; 
echo date('H:i d/m/Y ', $start_time_with_day+strtotime($time)-strtotime('midnight'));
// выводит 01:00 24/11/2019
```

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8c45bd124793ca7c7afaf36b10652344fbef36cd)

Answer (score 1):

Для работы с датой и временем в PHP есть DateTime в которых учтены подводные камни.

Пример для вашего случая:

```
<?php
$start_time_with_day = new DateTime('2019-11-23 02:55');
echo $start_time_with_day->format('H:i d/m/Y');
echo "\n";
$start_time_with_day->add(new DateInterval('PT22H5M'));
echo $start_time_with_day->format('H:i d/m/Y');
echo "\n";
```

Документация по использованию: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.datetime.php